# How to open a PST with CDO installed on exchange server machine?

Tags: perl, exchange-server, outlook-redemption, pst

I want to read a standalone PST file on Exchange server machine. As Microsoft suggested we can't install the Outlook client on exchange server.I have installed the Exchange client and CDO 1.2 library on server. But still I am not able to open the PST file using redemption library. Here is the sample Perl code. It returns the error *"Can't call method "LogonPstStore" on an undefined value"*.

```
$session = Win32::OLE->CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession");
$session->LogonPstStore("C:\test\ssn1.pst");
```

The same code works well if I have the outlook installed on the machine. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error means the `$session` variable is undefined. Is your code running in 32 bit?

Also note that Outlook can be installed on a server just fine - MS does not recommend **using** Outlook on a server since there is no interactive user there.

Comment: Thank you very much Dimitry. The issue is resolved after using the 64 bit Perl along with 64 bit redemption.

Answer (score 0):

Independent of other problems: Beware of your inadvertently use of metacharacters in the file string: '\t' and '\s' in your doublequoted string are most likely not, what you want, is it?

Either use a singlequoted string or double the backslashes...

```
$session->LogonPstStore('C:\test\ssn1.pst');
```

or

```
$session->LogonPstStore("C:\\test\\ssn1.pst");
```